# How to do a 3D plot of gaussian using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, plot, gaussian, normal-distribution

I'm trying to plot a gaussian function using numpy.
the funtion is z=exp(-(x**2+y**2)/10) but I only get a 2D function

```
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(-10,10, num=100)
y=np.linspace(-10,10, num=100)
z=np.exp(-0.1*x**2-0.1*y**2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(x,y,z)
```

I obtain: [image: only obtain 2D gaussian [1]]

but I want to obtain: [image: obtained a 3D gaussian but using sympy[2]]

I'm using numpy becouse I need the set of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to obtain the correct dimensions. This can be done using [`meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html). Also, your desired plot is a surface plot, not a wireframe (though you can do that too).

```
# import for colormaps
from matplotlib import cm

x=np.linspace(-10,10, num=100)
y=np.linspace(-10,10, num=100)

x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

z = np.exp(-0.1*x**2-0.1*y**2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x,y,z, cmap=cm.jet)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `z = np.exp(-0.1*x**2-0.1*y**2)`.  Using this, I believe you can avoid the `reshape` as well

Answer (score 2):

given the original formula of a gaussian distribution I wrote the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D # <--- This is important for 3d plotting 
A = 1
x0 = 0
y0 = 0

sigma_X = 2
sigma_Y = 2

xg = np.linspace(-5,5,num=100)
yg = np.linspace(-5,5,num=100)

theta= np.pi

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xg,yg)

a = np.cos(theta)**2/(2*sigma_X**2) + np.sin(theta)**2/(2*sigma_Y**2);
b = -np.sin(2*theta)/(4*sigma_X**2) + np.sin(2*theta)/(4*sigma_Y**2);
c = np.sin(theta)**2/(2*sigma_X**2) + np.cos(theta)**2/(2*sigma_Y**2);

aXXdet = np.array([a*(Xi-x0)**2 for Xi in X],float)
bbXYdet = np.array([2*b*(Xi-x0)*(Y[ii]-y0) for ii,Xi in enumerate(X)],float)
cYYdet = np.array([c*(Yi-y0)**2 for Yi in Y],float)
Z = np.array([A*np.exp( - (ai + bbXYdet[i] + cYYdet[i])) for i,ai in enumerate(aXXdet)],float);

# plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
plt.show()
```

which also plots the distribution. So you could play around with the parameters and see their effect!